# How to add data to table dynamically using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have 3 dropdowns and a button "Add", when i select the dropdowns and click on add, it has to insert into a table using JQuery and DataTables.How will i add rows dynamically? I have done using a for loop iteratin a list and then adding to the datatable but thisis different.pls help me in this regard,

```
 function addToTable(){

     var project = document.getElementById("projectId").value;
     var process = document.getElementById("glbProcessId").value;
     var role = document.getElementById("roleId").value;

            var t = $('#example').DataTable();


            $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
                t.row.add( [
                   // ##### how do i add the data here???##############
                ] );


            } );

 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, I have just added static values in it:

```
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
   t.row.add( [
      "1st Column's data",
      "2nd Column's data",
      "3rd Column's data",
      "4th Column's data",
       //and so on as based on number of your columns
   ]).draw();
});
```

If you want to add dynamic values, you can add an Ajax function above `t.row.add` line and then pass those values instead of static values.

For more reference [see this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html).